# Couldn't save the result of addition of two fields in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo-10

I'm trying to make a custom module in `Odoo` 10. And I need to find sum of two fields. So I used `onchange` and it showing calculated changes correctly but when I click save the changes are gone.

here is my code:

```
a = fields.Float()
b = fields.Float()
total = fields.Float(string="Total")

@api.onchange('b')
def onchange_field(self):
    if self.b:
        self.total = self.a + self.b
```

Please help me to solve this.

All helps are much appreciated!!

Comment: I hope this link will be to resolve your problems https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html#onchange

Comment: The field total is on readonly ?

Comment: @khelilimiliana Ya it is solved. The issue was the total field was readonly. Thanks for the solution.